# How do I access the serial ports on the RPi in LXterminal?

Tags: linux, serial, bash

I am trying to get access to the `/dev/ttyS0` file in an attempt to connect an OPC to the RPi via TX and RX connection.

However, when I am in the `/dev` directory, when I type in `/dev/ttyS0` I get the message: "Permission denied."
How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: have you tried sudo?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your question is literal.

You can't execute a device as a program.

If you want to see what is arriving on /dev/ttyS0 do

`cat </dev/ttyS0`

If you want to write to /dev/ttyS0 do

`echo "text" >/dev/ttyS0`

Normally you write a program to talk to the serial link or use something like minicom to debug.

If this doesn't help could you edit your question and show the result of

`ls -l /dev/ttyS0`

and

`stty -F /dev/ttyS0`

If your permissions are not correct you may need to precede the commands with `sudo`.

Comment: When I do the command 'cat </dev/ttyS0' I get 'bash: /dev/ttyS0: No such file or directory'

Comment: Do I need to create a '/dev/ttyS0' file?

Comment: Which model Pi are you using?

Comment: Model A, one of the first Pi's

Comment: It turns out I just solved the problem by using /dev/ttyUSB0, however I am pretty confused why that worked. Initially I had the tx and rx pins on a device hooked up to a VGA to USB converter which then plugged into the Pi USB port. I wanted to remove this VGA converter so I connected the TX and RX pins from the device to the Pi's TX and RX pins (as well as ground). I thought that I would need to change this /dev file in my python script to some sort of serial port (/dev/ttyS0) but I guess not. Do you know why this is?

Comment: No idea.  The TX/RX (pins 8/10) are /dev/ttyAMA0 except on the Pi3 where they are /dev/ttyS0 (or /dev/serial I think now).

Answer (score 1):

As has been answered in the comments, Raspberry Pis don't generally have a `/dev/ttyS0` device. The GPIO serial port is typically `/dev/ttyAMA0`, although that's not always the case on a Raspberry Pi 3.

All available serial ports belong to the *dialout* group, so for convenient read/write access it's best to issue this command once:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi
```

(This may be a default now on Raspbian.) You need to log out and back in again for this change to work, but then it should be valid indefinitely.

Serial ports can also have aliases. `/dev/serial0` (or `dev/serial1` by default on a 3) points to `/dev/ttyAMA0`. There are also the `/dev/serial/by-path/*` and `/dev/serial/by-id/*` devices that can be helpful for identifying particular ports. If you have multiple USB serial devices, the system will allocate `ttyUSB0` to the first one identified, `ttyUSB1` to the next, and so on. These aren't always in the same order, so the by-path and by-id aliases help you find the right physical port.

Answer (score 0):

I use them all the time.

Usually it will be /dev/ttyUSB0

but for some Chinese Arduino Unos it can be /dev/ttyACM0.

The way you find out is to do a

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

then connect your device and do it again.

You will see where it has appeared in the list.

### You must be a member of the `dialout` group to use them.

If you install Arduino IDE it will automatically add you.